# What should I do if I have been away from writing a dissertation for some time?

Tags: thesis

The subject of my research is very broad and has many aspects. I have measured the aspects many times before and thought about related topics. But I've been away from doing research for a while, I've collected a lot of books and articles. It is difficult for me to choose and organize them. 
How do I regenerate my mind?

Comment: What is "awhile"? Long enough that some of your research might have already been published?

Comment: I agree, some specifics would help.  My first thought was ``ask Brian May'' who took a 30 year break.